# CommitSync in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm using `commitSync()` after processing of messages in Kafka. I wanted to know for how much time `commitSync()` tries to commit before raising an error? And if it gives an error then would the same message be polled again later or it is assumed to be consumed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't specify a timeout, `commitSync()` blocks for the duration specified by `default.api.timeout.ms`. This is 60 seconds by default.

If it fails, that consumer instance will not poll the same messages again, it is considering consumed.

However, if that consumer instance was to crash, a new instance using the same consumer group would restart from the last successfully committed position.